# How can we show that the one subgroup is a subset of the other subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,M\leq G$.

$[H,M]$ symbolizes the subgroup of $G$ that is generated by all the $[h,m]$ with $h\in H$ and $m\in M$.

I want to show that $H\subseteq N_G(M)$ iff $[H,M]\subseteq M$.

$$$$

We have that $$N_G(M)=\{g\in G\mid gM=Mg\}$$

$$$$

How do the elements of the form $[h,m]$ look like?

$$$$

To show the iff statement we suppose first that $H\subseteq N_G(M)$.

Then for $h\in H \Rightarrow h\in N_G(M)$.

So $hM=Mh \Rightarrow M=h^{-1}Mh$.

But how exactly do we show that $[H,M]\subseteq M$ ?

Comment: $[h,m]$ is the commutator of $h$ and $m$, i.e. $[h,m] = h^{-1}m^{-1}hm$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $[h,m]$ is $h^{-1}m^{-1}hm$. Take an arbitrary generator of $[H,M]$, $[h,m] = h^{-1}m^{-1}hm$. By your assumption, conjugation by $h$ preserves $M$, so $h^{-1}m^{-1}h\in M$, which implies that $[h,m]\in M$. As $[H,M]$ is the subgroup generated by the $[h,m]$, and each $[h,m]\in M$, $[H,M]$ must be contained in $M$.